# Searching for multiple values in multiple lines for every unique value in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 3 fields 1:) Invoice number 2:) invoice sub number and 3:) invoice amount. Every unique invoice number might have multiple Invoice sub numbers. The requirement is that for every unique invoice number in the multiple lines if the invoice sub number begins with 1200 and 2100 then a dummy column should be introduced which will say "Both 1200 and 2100 exists", else if the lines have a invoice sub number beginning with 1200 the dummy column should be "has only 1200", else it should say "has only 2100". example is given below

```
S.no Invoice #    Invoice Sub Number    Amount    Dummy
----------------------------------------------
 1.   1234              1230             $100  Both 2100 and 1200 exists
 2.   1234              2100             $100  Both 2100 and 1200 exists
 3.   1234              1200             $100  Both 2100 and 1200 exists
 4.   1245              5430             $50   Only 1200 exists 1245      
 5.   1245              1200             $80   Only 1200 exists
```

I Tried the following command in python but it is not working need help on the same
Command  used

```
df1= df
df1['Invoice #'] = df1['Invoice #'].astype(object)
df['Invoice sub Number'] = df['Invoice sub Number'].astype(str)
df1= df1.groupby(df['Invoice sub Number','Invoice #'].size().groupby(level=0).size())

df1['dummy']= np.where(df1['Invoice sub Number'].str.startswith ('1200'),'Contains 1200 only',
               np.where(df1['Invoice sub Number'].str.startswith ('2100'),'Contains 2100 only',
                        np.where((df1['Invoice sub Number'].str.startswith ('1200'))&(df1['Invoice sub Number'].str.startswith ('2100')),
                                 'Contains both 1200 and 2100','Contains neither 1200 nor 2100')))
```

Error i am getting:- `KeyError: ('Invoice sub Number', 'Invoice #')`

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: because error means there is no column `Invoice sub Number` and `Invoice #`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for check at least one `True`s per groups and then for column by conditions [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

Use:

```
print (df)
    Invoice #  Invoice sub Number  Amount
0         123                1234     100
1         123                2345     200
2         123                3456     300
3         123                1200     400
4         123                2100     500
5        1234                1245     600
6        1234                2344     700
7        1234                1200     800
8        2345                 345     900
9        2345                2100    1000
10       2345                2458    1100
11       6789                2345    1200
12       6789                3421    1300
13       6789                1234    1400

m1 = df['Invoice sub Number'].astype(str).str.startswith('1200')    
m2 = df['Invoice sub Number'].astype(str).str.startswith('2100')

m11 = m1.groupby(df['Invoice #']).transform('any')
m22 = m2.groupby(df['Invoice #']).transform('any')

masks =[ m11 & m22 , m11, m22]
vals = ['Contains both 1200 and 2100', 'Contains 1200 only','Contains 2100 only']
default = 'Contains neither 1200 nor 2100'         

df['dummy'] = np.select(masks, vals, default=default)
```

---

```
print (df)
    Invoice #  Invoice sub Number  Amount                           dummy
0         123                1234     100     Contains both 1200 and 2100
1         123                2345     200     Contains both 1200 and 2100
2         123                3456     300     Contains both 1200 and 2100
3         123                1200     400     Contains both 1200 and 2100
4         123                2100     500     Contains both 1200 and 2100
5        1234                1245     600              Contains 1200 only
6        1234                2344     700              Contains 1200 only
7        1234                1200     800              Contains 1200 only
8        2345                 345     900              Contains 2100 only
9        2345                2100    1000              Contains 2100 only
10       2345                2458    1100              Contains 2100 only
11       6789                2345    1200  Contains neither 1200 nor 2100
12       6789                3421    1300  Contains neither 1200 nor 2100
13       6789                1234    1400  Contains neither 1200 nor 2100
```

Comment: But how can this be used for unique invoice number do we add in a for  loop for unique and then use the above code? cause i need 4 print outs as output 1:) for all that contains 1200, 2:) all invoice # line items which contain only 2100 3:) all invoice numbers which has both 1200 and 2100 and 4:) all invoice numbers which does not have both. Also the code "m1 = df1['Invoice sub Number'].str.startswith ('1200')   " is giving a Keyerror for Invoice sub Number

Comment: 'Invoice sub Number', 'Invoice #','Amount(DC)'  and then there are other feilds

Comment: i think when we are grouping it all the other columns are removed hence we are getting the error

Comment: @Krishnamurthy - Sorry, in code was error, Please check now.

Comment: i wanted for a group of line items not at individual line item like if you see in the required output as given above

Comment: @Krishnamurthy - Maybe my problem is dont understand your expected output. Can you add final DataFrame from your input data to question?

Comment: anyway i can contact you?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy - OK, can you send me sample data csv, expected output? I have email in my profile

Comment: mail sent across to you

Comment: @Krishnamurthy - Now understand, thank you. please check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jezrael for the help